# React+Redux - managing state for autocomplete inputs

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a large app with some autocomplete text-inputs that retrieve search suggestions from the backend on every key stroke.
I want to save recent search query results to avoid multiple backend calls for the same query if the user deletes characters. I also want to expire these queries after some period of time to keep search results fresh.
I also want to have a `loading` indicator for the current text input if the backend call isn't complete yet for that exact value.

The question is - where to manage this state and the actions associated with this state (below I have a sample state shape I need).

Managing it in the main Redux store looks like an overkill - this state is kind of temporary-intermediate state, it's very short-lived (queries should be expired after a while), there may be many instances of the same Component present on the screen, and different instances might use different backend calls.
Managing the recent search-queries and search-results in the local React Component `state` object - looks like a fine solution.

But now we have the backend calls which I don't want to fire from within the component, but go through the full-blown Flux process, with proper actions and reducers and passing the results (or errors) into props through the Store Connector.

So eventually, things here don't fit properly with each other - I don't want to manage the state in the main Redux store but I do want the backend-calls (results of which are the main part of that state) to go through the main reducers+store lifecycle.

Any advice for a robust, *maintainable*, and *easy-to-figure-out-without-docs* architecture is appreciated.

The state I need for every instance of this component looks something like:

(let's say I typed in `dog`, and the last result didn't come yet):

```
{ 
    currentSearchInput: 'dog',
    recentQueries: [
      {
        input: 'd',
        isLoading: false,
        results: [...]
      },
      {
        input: 'do',
        isLoading: false,
        results: [...]
      },
      {
        input: 'dog',
        isLoading: true,
        results: null
      },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using the object structure noted above with the components internal state is just fine. Write a function that will accept the results of the HTTP Request that come back through Redux, and update the `results` field of the appropriate object in the array. Personally, I would store the promise in the results field. Each time `componentWillReceiveProps` gets called (due to your reducers returning new redux state) use a setState to update your recentQueries.

I'd also set a limit. 5 recent query max or something like that.

That being said, I use the google places API to return address/establishment suggestions and the data is so small it wasn't worth it to do this. Most of the results are under 10kb.

EDIT:

Based on our discussions in the comments, here is what I would suggest doing.

In the onChange handler for the input.

Pass the search criteria to the action as you normally would

In the action creator, return the results of the API call AND the search criteria

In the reducer

Check to see the length of the array that holds your search calls (the redux store value). If it is less than five, simply concat the current values and the new values and return. If its value, overwrite the 0th position of the array with the new content. e.g.

`state[0] = action.newApiResult; return state;`

Comment: But now we are storing the results both in the main store and the local component state. It can't just "come back through redux"; for that it needs to be stored in the state by the reducer and then passes through props, and then you suggest saving it again in component state.

Comment: I do agree however with the idea of saving only the recent 5 or so.

Comment: When I say come back through redux, I meant the results of your API calls only. As the API call should be dispatched by an action, which triggers an action creator.

Comment: Yes, but the result of the dispatch is passes to the reducer, which returns a new state. So we have the result in the main state.

Comment: Correct. If your concern is not wanting to have the state stored in the component and redux, then in your reducer instead of returning an object for your results (or whatever you are returning) just concat the new information to that state object.

e.g. 

`return state.currentWhatever.concat(action.newWhatever)`

if you use the limiting we talked about, you wouldn't need to expire them either.

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope that sheds some light on it. Its simple and doesn't require additional action creators or changes to the component itself.